# How to migrated emails and contacts from Outlook Express Email to Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, migration, outlook-express

I have tried taking the Outlook Express 6 `.dbx` files to a Windows 7 machine and importing, but there is no browse.

I then installed Outlook 2010 on the XP machine with Outlook Express and only got a partial import success.

How can I migrate my data from Outlook Express to Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Only via Live Mail first.

Import Outlook Express Email into Live Mail

```
Download and install the Microsoft Live Mail client
Open it and go to File, Import Messages.
Select to import from Outlook Express 6
Browse to the Outlook Express folder you copied from the old computer.
Select the folders you want to import and finish the wizard.
```

You'll need to export the messages and address book from Live Mail to Outlook.

```
Go to File, Export, Messages
Choose Microsoft Exchange.
Pick the folders and finish the export.
```

Open the Live Mails' Contact module and export the addresses in CSV or vCard format then import in into Outlook. If you export as vCard format, you can drag and drop them from the file system into Outlook's Contacts.

There are also ways to [convert from Outlook express .dbx to Outlook .pst](http://www.dbxconverter.com/)

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't gotten this yet there is a free tool that extract the messages out of the dbx files into .eml files. after that you can simply drag and drop them into outlook

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/E-mail/Mail-Utilities/DbxConv.shtml